# can't find node_export_feeds module

Tags: 6, updating, importing-exporting

I want to migrate nodes from a drupal 6 site into a fresh drupal 7 site.
Looking at the [node export module](http://drupal.org/project/node_export), under **Migrating nodes between Drupal versions
** it says you need to enable *node export feeds* and use the feeds module in D7 to import. Obviously I downloaded and installed the node export module and enabled all the submodules, but there simply isn't any node export feeds module listed within those.

All I'm seeing listed on my sites modules page under node export is:

- Node export
- Node export DSV
- Node export features
- Node export files
- Node export relation
- Node export serialize
- Node export XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable the Node Export Feeds module and the Feeds module on the **D7 site** and import the nodes via the Feeds user interface from the D6 site.

Make sure you enable the Feeds Import and Feeds Admin UI modules as well on the D7 site

Comment: That would make sense :)

Comment: sorry about that :)